# missing values in dictionary what merged

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary `a = {1:6, 2:7, 3:8}` and `b = {1:5, 3:9}`
I want to merge them in this shape
`c = {1:[6, 5], 2:[7, null], 3:[8, 9]}`
And another thing is I have more than 2 dictionaries they are lots of dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question originally had a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag:

```
import pandas as pd

out = (pd.concat([pd.Series(a), pd.Series(b)], axis=1) # as many series as you want
         .convert_dtypes().replace({pd.NA: None}) # optional
         .T.to_dict('list')
       )
```

output: `{1: [6, 5], 2: [7, None], 3: [8, 9]}`

##### any number of dictionaries

```
import pandas as pd

dicts = [a, b, c, d] # add all the dictionaries in the list

out = (pd.concat([pd.Series(d) for d in dicts], axis=1)
         .convert_dtypes().replace({pd.NA: None}) # optional
         .T.to_dict('list')
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for asking I have lots of dictionaries in a list and your anwer is just for 2 dictionaries

Comment: @Novinnam my answer is for any number of dictionaries. See update

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
a = {1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8}
b = {1: 5, 3: 9}

out = {}
for k in a.keys() | b.keys():
    out[k] = [a.get(k), b.get(k)]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: [6, 5], 2: [7, None], 3: [8, 9]}
```

---

Or one-liner:

```
out = {k: [a.get(k), b.get(k)] for k in a.keys() | b.keys()}
```

---

For more dicts:

```py
a = {1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8}
b = {1: 5, 3: 9}
c = {2: 1, 3: 10}

all_dicts = [a, b, c]

out = {}
for k in {k for d in all_dicts for k in d}:
    out[k] = [d.get(k) for d in all_dicts]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: [6, 5, None], 2: [7, None, 1], 3: [8, 9, 10]}
```

Comment: Asking due to my ignorance, is there a reason for `a.keys()` over `a` when using dict/list comprehension? Or is it a case of explicit > implicit?

Comment: @CeliusStingher `a.keys() | b.keys()` will give me set of keys found in both dictionaries `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: Thanks for asking I have lots of dictionaries in a list and your anwer is just for 2 dictionaries

Comment: @Novinnam See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set.union` to get the union keys of two dictionary

```py
d = {k: [a.get(k), b.get(k)]  for k in set(a).union(set(b))}
```

```
print(d)

{1: [6, 5], 2: [7, None], 3: [8, 9]}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I have lots of dictionaries and your answer is for just 2 dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

***Update base the comment for multiple dicts***

You can `union` keys of multiple `dicts` by using `set().union(*dcts)` *(because dict return keys)*. At the end we can use `dict.get()` and the default value of this function is `None` if the key doesn't exist.

```
a = {1:6, 2:7, 3:8}
b = {1:5, 3:9}
c = {1:7, 3:10, 4:11}

dcts = [a, b, c]

res = {k: [dct.get(k) for dct in dcts] for k in set().union(*dcts)}
print(res)
```

---

```
{1: [6, 5, 7], 2: [7, None, None], 3: [8, 9, 10], 4: [None, None, 11]}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking I have lots of dictionaries in a list and your anwer is just for 2 dictionaries

Comment: @Novinnam, welcome, edited answer, you can create `list` from your `dict` then merge all of them like the answer. I update answer for three dicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your longest dictionary in a kind of left join operation:

```
new = {x:[a.get(x,None),b.get(x,None)] for x in a}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking I have lots of dictionaries in a list and your anwer is just for 2 dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function using a loop through the distinct keys:

```
def combine(*dicts):
    return {k: [d.get(k) for d in dicts] for k in set().union(*dicts)}
```

---

```
>>> combine(a, b)
{1: [6, 5], 2: [7, None], 3: [8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1:6, 2:7, 5:8}
b = {1:5, 3:9}
c = {}

max_key = max(max(list(a.keys())), max(list(b.keys())))

for i in range(max_key):
    c[i+1] = [a.get(i+1), b.get(i+1)]

print(c)
```

Result:

```
{1: [6, 5], 2: [7, None], 3: [None, 9], 4: [None, None], 5: [8, None]}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking I have lots of dictionaries in a list and your anwer is just for 2 dictionaries